# Array of pixel values for vImage PixelBuffer produces black bar in image

Tags: swift, accelerate, vimage

In the code shown below, I'm generating an array of RGB pixel values for the `vImage.PixelBuffer` and creating an image from that buffer. But the generated image contains a black bar. Any ideas on what is causing the black bar?

```swift
import Accelerate

let width = 200
let height = 200

var pixelValues = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: width * height * 3)

for i in 0..<pixelValues.count {
    pixelValues[i] = .random(in: 0...255)
}

let buffer = vImage.PixelBuffer(
    pixelValues: pixelValues,
    size: .init(width: width, height: height),
    pixelFormat: vImage.Interleaved8x3.self
)

let format = vImage_CGImageFormat(
    bitsPerComponent: 8,
    bitsPerPixel: 8 * 3,
    colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
    bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue)
)!

let image = buffer.makeCGImage(cgImageFormat: format)!
```

[image: pixels image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `CGImageAlphaInfo` `enum` value you are using says to skip over the unused alpha byte, but since you don't have an alpha byte, you should use `CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue` instead:

Change:

```
bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue)
```

To:

```
bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue)
```

Doing this gives the expected result.

Comment: Ok, that works. But I didn't think it would matter because the [docs for CGImageAlphaInfo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimagealphainfo) say "There is no alpha channel" for both `.none` and `.noneSkipLast`.

Comment: The skip is clearly causing a misalignment of the data.  I tried making the buffer all orange (R = 255, G = 128, B = 0) and the output was striped.  So the "none" part says I'm not using an alpha channel, and the skip part says "but there is a byte in the data that needs to be ignored".